# How to use two authentication providers in the same request with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have two authentication providers configured in my application, one using LDAP and other looking in the database:

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapServer" />
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="dbUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Spring tries to use LDAP first, and if it does not find the user there, it tries my custom provider.

What I want to do is force Spring to authenticate the user in all available providers. In this case, it will only try my custom provider if it can perform the login in the LDAP server first. If the authentication in the custom provider fails, the entire authentication fails.

Is it possible to achive this with Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement your own authentication provider, in which you inject two instances - one of LdapAuthenticationProvider and the other is DaoAuthenticationProvider.
You will have to implement a method

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
```

where you can proxy authentication call at first to LdapAuthenticationProvider and if it is successful then you call DaoAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: This is what I did. Looking at the source code, the `ProviderManager` implementation does not allow what I want to do using only XML configuration.